# How to access members of DeviceInformation class in cppwinrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

The winrt MIDI documentation sample code recommends that, given a DeviceInformation object, a MIDIPort can be created by reference to the Id of the DeviceInformation, like this, for a DeviceInformation named devInfo:

midiOutPort = await MidiOutPort.FromIdAsync(devInfo.Id);

In cppwinrt, of course, one would use a C++ version of that, but the sticking point is accessing the Id of devInfo (whether by devInfo.Id() or devInfo.Id or whatever). The error is that "DeviceInformation does not have a member named Id." Surely this exists in cppwinrt but I have not found the way to access it.

If it is relevant, I declared the DeviceInformation this way:

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IIterator<winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation> devInfo;
```

because winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation was not accepted when enumerating the DeviceInformationCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with [`IIterator<DeviceInformation>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.iiterator_t_), not `DeviceInformation`. To extract the data from IIterator, you need to call [`Current()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.iiterator_t_#Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterator_1_Current_). So, in your example:

```cpp
auto id = devInfo.Current().Id();
```

Also, C++/WinRT collections support range-based for loops, so you can bypass IIterator and iterate collections directly, like so:

```cpp
DeviceInformationCollection collection = ...; // Some initialization
for (const auto& info : collection)
{
  auto id = info.Id();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Ryan. That's terrific. Can I ask - is this stuff documented anywhere? Might save me asking so many questions. I know it's early days and complete C++ examples are not yet available for all of winrt, but looking at the winrt docs it's not clear to me how one can tell to use devinfo.Current().Id() in a case like this instead of the example's direct reference to .Id.

Comment: @user3743210: The type (`IIterator<T>`) is documented, and - lo and behold! - the language selector in the top right now contains "C++/WinRT" (that was new to me, too). I'm not aware of a design document detailing the language projection for C++, though. It would certainly help to know, which collection interfaces map to which standard C++ containers (if any), automatic convenience conversions, or even just the guiding principles. As I see it, you currently still need to be sufficiently experienced in COM and an expert in C++ to proficiently use C++/WinRT.

Comment: Well, I've written C++ for many years, at any rate; that and Objective-C being the main thing with Apple stuff - though I'd hardly call myself expert. I have no experience in COM - I think - though I've written WIn32 programs. Those mappings would indeed be valuable; not everyone is going to have expertise sufficient to this. Just an additional code example for each class would be terrific, in addition to have the Java, C#, managed C++, etc. I know that is a large project. But MS has lots of people!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that none of the material in this post (how to get at IIterator's value) was particular to C++/WinRT. That is part of the overall WinRT API surface,  which has been documented since long before I joined the project.

Comment: That said, the points about needing better documentation are valid. We're actively addressing the documentation gap,  as evidenced by our inclusion as as "official flavor" on learn.microsoft.com. Thanks for your patience, and your feedback!

Comment: 5 years later and the docs are still in the poorest shape possible. The failure in providing an example of enumerating COM ports "the modern way" makes developers every day stick to Win32 APIs. No one has hours to waste to be able to iterate over a collection just because Microsoft cannot offer proper guidance. No matter how good an API is, it's a waste if no one uses it. Typical Microsoft.